# Comparing input with a string in Shell Script

Tags: macos, shell, if-statement, command-line, sh

Hello i'm making a sh script with parameters.
I need that the user insert 1 parameter and use this in order to run scrapy istance.

```
#!/bin/sh
# sh yahooscraper.sh 

if [ -z "$1"]
then
    echo "ERROR you must enter one arg related to the Yahoo URL DB "
else
    if ["$1" = "-h"]
    then
        echo "msg"
    else
    echo "Reading from $1 database "
    cd yahooquestionscraper/yahooscraper/yahooscraper/spiders
    scrapy crawl yahoo -o yahoo-url-file.json -a database_name=$1
    fi
fi
```

This script works in the first case, when user don't choose any parameter and in the second else. But don't work in the if ["$1" = "-h"] condition.

Comment: `["$1" = "-h"]` => `[ "$1" = "-h" ]` (spaces are required)

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: This is also #10 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Answer (score 1):

You need a space after the `test` (`[`) command (and a space before the closing `]` argument):

```
if [ "$1" = "-h" ]
```

When writing shell scripts, it's worth checking them with http://shellcheck.net.